# Stop CKEDITOR from Copying the Previous Element class into each new element on page

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

By default, whatever element your cursor is inside of when you hit the enter key will be duplicated with all of the same attributes. If you set "forceEnterMode: true" in the CKEDITOR config file, you can force ckeditor to not duplicate the element and instead use the default element each time you hit enter (http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.forceEnterMode), but unfortunately the classes are still copied over into this new element.

To put it another way, if the code inside ckeditor is:

```
<div class="text">{{cursor here}}</div>
```

And you press the enter key twice. You'll get:

```
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text">{{cursor here}}</div>
```

I you then set forceEnterMode: true, and hit enter key, you'll get:

```
<div class="text"></div>
<div class="text"></div>
<p class="text">{{cursor here}}</p>
```

I'm not sure in what situation you would want your previous elements class to be copied into every future element as you spaced down the page, but I definitely don't want this functionality. I want the result to be this:

```
<div class="text"></div>
<p></p>
```

How can I force CKEDITOR to stop copying the previous element attributes into each new element of the page each time I hit the enter key?

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/158/

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you **can't** force CKEDITOR to stop copying the previous element attributes.

If you read through **enterkey** plugin [code on github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/enterkey/plugin.js#L37) carefully, you'll see that previous node is [cloned](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/enterkey/plugin.js#L342) with all attributes, inline styles and classes (only *id* is removed) and then inserted in it's [parent](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/enterkey/plugin.js#L377) or [bellow](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/enterkey/plugin.js#L385). Exception is made for **blockquote**, **li** and **pre** tags.

This totally makes sense, because usually we want to continue typing with chosen styles, event when new paragraph is created (as in any other editor).

If this behaviour is still annoying, you can manually use [magicline plugin](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_magicline.html) which forces line breaks between blocks or [remove text formatting](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_removeformat.html) from chosen block.

Answer (score 1):

listen to the 'enter' event on the editor and then get the element and do the needful the below code removed the data-element attribute from the new div created when the enter key is pressed. This answer is sort of late but it might still help someone :)

```
    editor.on('afterCommandExec', function (e) {
    if (e.data.name == 'enter') {
        var el = e.editor.getSelection().getStartElement();

        // modify el according to your needs
        el.removeAttribute('data-element', '')
    }
});
```